$a^2\left(b^2-4\right)-4$ cannot be a square number for $b\neq3$
Let $a,\,b\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$.
While playing around with numbers, I noticed by examples that when $a^2\left(b^2-4\right)-4$ was a square number, it was $b=3$.
Thus, my hypothesis is that $a^2\left(b^2-4\right)-4$ cannot be a square number for $b\neq3$.
This is obviously true for $b=1$ and $b=2$ but I don't have any idea how to prove that $a^2\left(b^2-4\right)-4$ cannot be a square number for $b>3$.
There is probably an easy argument that I'm missing, so I'd be grateful for any hints.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, in A natural number equation, there's this answer which states "... $(m^2-4)y_0^2 - 4$ is a perfect square" and "Mike Bennett below in comments asserts this does not have a solution except when $m=\pm 3$, ...". Note that $m=2n+1$ in this answer, so it's odd, and the rest of the answer provides an explanation for that. However, Mike's comment  ...

(cont.) states "Precisely correct. And, for $m\gt 3$ (even or odd), this equation has no solutions...". Since Mike is a number theory researcher, specializing in Diophantine equations, I would trust this comment. Thus, it appears your hypothesis is correct, but there's also apparently no "easy argument" that you're missing.

@JohnOmielan nice! I was just writing an answer citing the fact that the negative Pell's equation has solution if and only if the continued fraction of $\sqrt{d}$ has an odd period while $\sqrt{m^2-4}$ has even for $m>3.$

@JohnOmielan I didn't study mathematics, so all of this is a bit hard to understand. Is my following summary correct? $a^2\cdot\left(b^2-4\right)-4=n^2$ can be reduced to $n^2-a^2\cdot\left(b^2-4\right)=-1$ which is the negative Pell's equation.
Since $\sqrt{b^2-4}$ has an even period for $b>3$, the negative Pell's equation has no solution, thus $a^2\cdot\left(b^2-4\right)-4=n^2$ has no solution.

@summingsummer This is not something I'm really knowledgeable about either, but reducing the equation to the form of $n^2-a^2(b^2-4)=-1$ is stated to always be possible if $b$ is odd. However, I'm unsure offhand if that's always necessarily the case if $b$ is even. Otherwise, the rest of what you wrote is my understanding as well.

@JohnOmielan So I guess it's quite impossible for me to fully understand all the reasoning which leads to the conclusion, that $a^2\cdot\left(b^2-4\right)-4=n^2$ has no solution for $b>3$? I mean, I am able to articulate more questions, but that's quite a lot, so I'm unsure how to continue. Should I edit my question and append more questions? That feels wrong, because then I'd be asking a lot of questions in one question on math.stackexchange. Otherwise, I could open a new question for every question, but that feels also wrong, because the context of all the questions would be the same.

@summingsummer As the linked answer is the only method I'm currently aware of, it seems you'd need to be put in a fair bit of time & effort to fully understand it. However, since dezdichado stated they were writing an answer, assuming this will be completed, it may explain things in a way you can understand. Also, there might also be a simpler method that can solve your problem. Regarding doing something like updating your question or asking new ones, I agree you should try to avoid asking multiple questions in one, unless they are all very closely related, which may or not be the case here.

As a first step, it is plain that there are no solutions unless $b\equiv 0 \bmod 3$. Otherwise, $b^2\equiv 1$, $b^2-4 \equiv 0$, and $a^2(b^2-4)-4 \equiv 2 \bmod 3$, but there are no squares $\equiv 2 \bmod 3$

Lemma 1: If  $a,\,c\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$ and $ac\mid a^2+c^2+1$ then   $3ac=a^2+c^2+1$.
Proof: The example for constant descent Vieta jumping.
Now, to prove the hypothesis of the asked question, let $a,\,b\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$ and let $a^2\left(b^2-4\right)-4$ be a square number.
We define $c:=\frac{1}{2}\left(ab+\sqrt{a^2\left(b^2-4\right)-4}\right)$ which implies $c\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$.
The definition of $c$ yields $bac=a^2+c^2+1$.
Thus, $ac\mid a^2+c^2+1$.
Lemma 1 gives $b=3$.

one of the most unexpected applications of Vieta jumping I've ever seen.
